# Disable debug messages in gtkmm-3.0

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm

I have a application written in gtkmm-3.0. It works fine. But it's printing many messages on terminal. I found, in GTK+3.0 one can control this messages by --enable-debug=yes/no, but same is not working for gtkmm. Can you guide me how to stop this messages.
Messages are as bellow.
    (process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_cascade_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

```
(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:9750): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(process:9750): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(process:9750): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_cascade_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:9750): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(HMIApp:9750): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_steal_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(HMIApp:9750): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **:
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question; you don't want to turn off the messages, but fix the problem that is causing them.

Comment: Thanks ptomato. I understand what's wrong in ti.

Comment: You probably need to recompile gtkmm with the correct settings or check installation. where did you get gtkmm libs? and what compiler are you using?